# Image not getting displayed in ASP.NET in local host

Tags: c#, asp.net

There is an image in Images folder in my solution and I have an image controller on my page. and on a button click I set the URL of the image like this,

```
imgDisp.ImageUrl = @"~/Images/American.jpg";
```

But the image is not showing up on the browser when I run the code. The image is present in the specified folder and I didnt mention any URL in  tag either. What am I missing ? The image URL should be mentioned the above way when running in local host too or should it be done differently ? Thanks in advance for the reply.

Comment: What do you use for running it local? Web Development server\IIS\IIS Express?

Comment: Running in Visual studio. ASP.NET Development server

Comment: Try it without tilde.

Comment: the tilde stay for root path in example "localhost:123/" so it don't think it is the issue.A question why are using @? it is need?

Comment: @ is jus escape character. can be ignored. Doesnt work without ~ either

Comment: Do you get a 404 on http://localhost/Images/American.jpg ? Is the file's build action set to "Content"?

Comment: Can you paste the output of the HTML as well? It would help to better diagnose the issue

Comment: Maybe you forgot to include this file in your project? (Right-click on file in the solution explorer, then choose "include in project")